# Xcode view transparent background without influencing subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, view, transparency

I want to program a custom keyboard for a textfield. The background of
the keyboard should be transparent, but when I try to set the alpha of the
keyboardView, the alpha of its subviews changes too. How can I change the
keyboard's alpha only? I don't want to set it to [UIColor clearColor].

```
keyboardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
keyboardView.alpha = 0.2;
keyboardView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent];
```

Comment: Well I don't think it is possible to change the view but not it's subViews. The only thing I could imagine is to set it transparent **before** adding the subViews. Try that.

Comment: as you can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681901/setting-alpha-on-uiview-sets-the-alpha-on-its-subviews-which-should-not-happen      you can use next way: [parentView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];

Comment: It doesn't work setting it transparent before adding the subviews. And if I use setBackgroundColor: nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing a view's alpha alters the view and all it's subviews.

If you want the non-drawn parts of your view to show what's underneath, set the view's opaque flag to NO and then set the background color to clearColor.

Comment: When I try this, there stays a grey opaque layer in the background. Do you have any ideas how I could remove it?

Comment: It's probably one of your subviews. Try Selecting view debugging from the Xcode debug menu, and choose the "Capture View Hierarchy" menu item. Then rotate the resulting snapshot and look at the stack of views. Also try "Show view frames". You may need to set some of your subviews to opaque = NO and backgroundColor = clearColor as well.

Comment: Thank You for the hint, but I only see the view, my textfield is a subview of. So the keyboardView of this textfield isn't shown.