# Opacity not working in storyboard

Tags: ios, opacity

I'm trining to change view's background color to opacity 10% from the storyboard, but when I run it on a device the color looks like the opacity is at 100%.

Also, I would prefer to not do this from code.

So here is how I set it. And I want to get the gray color, but instead I get the black one. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting alpha on UIView sets the alpha on its subviews which should not happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681901/setting-alpha-on-uiview-sets-the-alpha-on-its-subviews-which-should-not-happen)

Comment: Please see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681901/setting-alpha-on-uiview-sets-the-alpha-on-its-subviews-which-should-not-happen/48014487#48014487

Comment: You can apply alpha to color and view itself. So check which one should have alpha and change value for that property.

Comment: Are you trying to set the *view* to 10% (light) gray? Or are you trying to set the view to ***add 10% gray*** to whatever is behind it?

Comment: @DonMag The first one. I'm trying to set the view to 10% (light) gray

Comment: @razvan - OK, that's not what Opacity does. Just set each of the R/G/B values to `25`, and leave Opacity at `100`... actually, that will be **dark gray**. If you want **light gray**, set the values to `225` and Opacity `100` (adjust the `225` value till you find your happy gray color).

Comment: @DonMag as Emre Önder pointed out and I just realized that I actually get the color that I want, it's just that I have a black view under it. Thanks a lot all of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check If you have any View below that view. Also check If you are selecting right view. When I set RGB to 0 and make opacity to %10. I'm getting a light gray as you want.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Oooh, you are right. I didn't think that might be the problem. I actually get the color that I want, it's just that I have a black view under it. Thanks

Comment: Good luck. Can you please tick it as approved :)